# Sorting score from text file into average

Tags: python

I need to develop a program that sorts the scores from a quiz from a text file into averages into Python. The program uses previous data from the text file that includes the name of the person with a score attached. The code would have to open the file, read the data and then display it by the average score in Python. Is there any help as I have no previous code.

Comment: Welcome, As you may know SO is a country that its language is **Code** so you need to add your code to your question! if you want to get a desire answer!

Comment: Your code seems totally unrelated to whatever you are asking.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to have us help solve a homework assignment. While that's alright (I think), you really should think about what the actual, concrete question is first.

Comment: the code is for writing the scores to a file. The code i need is to sort the information added into average scores

Comment: @mike this isn't a code-writing or tutorial service. In the likely event that this is your GCSE coursework, *talk to your teacher* if you're stuck.

Comment: thanks then but i was just asking for guidance i didnt want it doing for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary with the keys as the class names and the value as a dictionary with student names as the keys and a list to store their scores as the value. Then use the [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module to [`json.dump()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump) the data to a file. When you want to add a new score: [`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) the file, add the score like you would with a normal dictionary, and dump the `json.dump()` the data back into the file. First read the documentation and try to do this on your own. If you get stuck, comment on my answer with the specific problem you are having and a pastebin to the code in question. Good luck!